# Creating Multiple txt files from XML output using Python and beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an XML page that I want to separate into sections and then take the text from each of the sections and separate them into a .txt file with the saved name starting from 001 and going to 099. For example I want all of Section 1 in a file named 001 and all of Section 2 in a file named 002 and so on. This is what I have so far:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.govinfo.gov/bulkdata/CFR/2018/title-49/CFR-2018-title49-vol1.xml/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

for paragraph in soup.find_all('section'):
print(paragraph.string)
print(str(paragraph.text))
```

I want to know what I could use to create the incremental txt file output with the sections saved in their respective files.

Comment: Ok that's a fair statement, but what is your question ?

Comment: what I could use to create the incremental txt file output with the sections saved in their respective files?

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear, or too broad. What is your problem ? You have problem with creating a file ? You have problem with fixing the name of the files ? You have problem with incremental structure ? You have problem with getting the index of the sections ?

Comment: I do not know how to create the index of the sections and then display the data in a separate txt file.

Comment: Does the sections already got an index in the xml file ? If yes, parse your file to get this info, else create an int variable, and just increment it in your for loop, This will be your index.

Comment: In each loop, create a new file with the index in the name of the file. Then write the current section in this file.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To group all the sections together, you can make use of Python's [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function. This takes a function which extracts the section number from a paragraph. The groupby function then creates a list of all paragraphs with the same section number and returns them together:

```
from itertools import groupby
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

def section(paragraph):
    return paragraph.sectno.text.strip('§ ').split('.')[0]


source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.govinfo.gov/bulkdata/CFR/2018/title-49/CFR-2018-title49-vol1.xml/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for section_number, paragraphs in groupby(soup.find_all('section'), section):
    filename = f'Section {int(section_number):02}.txt'

    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
        section_text = '\n-------------\n'.join(p.text for p in paragraphs)
        f_output.write(section_text)
```

Here the files would look like:

```
Section 01.txt
Section 03.txt
Section 05.txt
Section 06.txt
Section 07.txt
Section 08.txt
...
Section 10.txt
Section 80.txt
Section 89.txt
Section 91.txt
Section 92.txt
Section 93.txt
Section 98.txt
Section 99.txt
```

Each paragraph is also separated with a small line.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to click on the grey tick to select the answer as the accepted solution.